# I would like to install clang-tidy as a linter for cpp on CentOS 7 but cannot locate a package

Tags: c++, centos7, clang-tidy

I was able to install both llvm and clang via the epel repository.  However, they do not include the clang-tidy binary.  I have been searching the llvm website but they do not have any packages available for CentOS 7.  The ius repository doesn't have clang-tidy either.  I would like to double check before I build from source.  Thank you.

Comment: i went ahead and started building from source

Comment: I have a 4G cloud server with nothing running.  I was compiling llvm with cfe and the clang-tools-extra and ld process was killed due to out of memory with no swap.

Comment: Feb  1 21:58:23 darkterminal kernel: Killed process 18955 (ld) total-vm:3356760kB, anon-rss:3241772kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Comment: I'm going to try an 8G swap but man it will be slow.

Comment: build was at 91% and oom killer killed ld again this time to hard disk space.  There was roughly 42G on the build directory.  This build is huge.

Comment: The default build config is Debug which is huge. Build the Release (or MinSizeRel) configuration, it's much smaller.

Answer (score 7):

Consider installing `centos-release-scl` to get access to [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/), then install `llvm-toolset-7-clang-tools-extra`. You can get access it with `scl enable llvm-toolset-7 bash` or directly at `/opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7/root/bin/clang-tidy`

Comment: Plus you get a newer version of clang.